# filling values in array

Tags: java, arrays

what i want to do is fill the empty aray kyo[] with the add() method but it keeps getting an error:

> Exception in thread "main"  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   0     at TestPlass.Add(TestPlass.java:30)     at
>   TestPlass.main(TestPlass.java:18)

i'm just new to programming

```
public static int size = 30;
public static void main (String args[]) {
    int kyo[] = {};

    Add(kyo);

    for(int x:kyo){
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
}

static void Add(int x[]){
    for(int g=0; g<=size; g++){
        x[g] = g;
    }
}
```

Comment: please check out a tutorial, like: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your kyo array has a fized size, you need to create it with this size.

```
public static int size = 30;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int kyo[] = new int[size];

    add(kyo);

    for (int x : kyo) {
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
}

static void add(int x[]) {
    for (int g = 0; g < x.length; g++) {
        x[g] = g;
    }
}
```

You add function receives `int x[]` as input, so it should use `x.length` for the iterator and not your size variable.

I have also edited the name of your `Add()` method to be `add()` to respect Java code conventions.

Comment: oh i didn't know there is a naming conventions.... back to the question the i tried this the error is still the same.

Comment: @tinker101 I have tested my code and it's working. Have you changed both `int kyo[] = new int[size];` and  `for (int g = 0; g < x.length; g++) {`?

Comment: oh yea it run now i put <=x.lenght that's why i get error

Answer (score 0):

An empty array can *never* have any content.

Once an array has been created, its size is fixed - you can change the content of the elements, but you can't change how many elements it has. See the [Java arrays tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more information.

If you need a dynamically-sized collection, I suggest you use a `List<E>` implementation, such as `ArrayList<E>`:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
add(list);
for (int x : list) {
    System.out.print(x + " ");
}

...

private static void add(List<Integer> list) {
    // I assume you want "size" elements, not "size + 1"
    for (int g = 0; g < size; g++) {
        list.add(g);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
int kyo[] = {};
```

creates an array of size zero. Arrays have a fixed size in Java; once an array has been created, its size is fixed. You have to create the array like this:

```
int[] kyo = new int[30];
```

This will create an array with 30 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the size of the array when you create it, like:

```
int kyo[] = new int[size];
```

You can find some great info on arrays here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Arrays do not resize themselves automatically, so the size you initialize it with will be its size forever.

Cheers,
Marcus

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here: `int kyo[] = {};`

{} Creates an array of zero size. Since you are adding 31 elements to the array you need to initialize you array to appropriate size.

For example: `int[] kyo = new int[31];`